# Selecting from joined tables in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :posts
end

class Posts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like to join these associations (with some conditions on both topics and posts), so I did `Topic.joins(:forum, :posts).where(some condition)`, but I would like to access the attributes in all three tables. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a multiple join like that.  All three tables are available, you just have to specify in the wheres.

```
Topic.joins(:forum, :posts).where('topics.foo' => 'bar').where('posts.whizz' => 'bang)
```

The two caveats are that that is a multiple inner join so the topic will need to have both forum and post to show up at all and that the where's are anded together.  For outer joins or 'or' logic in the where's you will have to get fancier.  But you can write sql for both .joins and .where to make that happen.  Using .includes instead of .joins is another way to get outer join behavior--but of course you are then maybe loading a lot of records.

To clarify the comment below, and show the improved (more rails-y) syntax where syntax suggested by another user:

```
topics = Topic.joins(:forum, :posts).where(topic: {foo: 'bar'}).where(posts: {whizz: 'bang'})
topics.each do |t|
   puts "Topic #{t.name} has these posts:"
   t.posts.each do |p|
     puts p.text
   end
end
```

Comment: I would rather use `.where(topics: { foo: 'bar' })`: it lets Rails deals with the DB adapter to set the proper syntax

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! However I'm still new to rails so may I ask how can I access, say Post.text from the result above? I tried `topic.post.text` and `topic.text` in the .each block but I can't get the 'post'.'text' column? I can do `topic.forum` since a topic belongs to one forum...

Comment: That's a good point MrYoshiji.  Your way would handle custom table names more elegantly.

Comment: So since a topic has many posts, you are going to have to pick a post before you can access a field.  Eg topic.posts.first.text would work (I'm not saying it's pretty).  More likely you want to iterate over the posts and refer to the posts in the block.  This would suggest .includes instead of .joins might be called for.